# Why Zabbix still says "At least one of MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite3 or IBM DB2 should be supported."?

Tags: php, monitoring, oracle, zabbix

At begin of setup, **Zabbix** shows the following error:

`At least one of MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite3 or IBM DB2 should be supported.`

I already have a site working, and this have connections to a Oracle database, because I've installed oci8-2.0.8 via phpize.

[phpinfo shows that is able to connect to a Oracle database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPwgp.png)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, I've installed oci8 via phpize.

The solution was reinstall occi8 via pecl:

```
pecl install oci8-2.0.8
```

[Now, phpinfo shows specific information about oci8, not about PDO as before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/583Ps.png)